# Ubuntu 16.04 - Fans not detected Laptop heats

Tags: 16.04, fan, sensors, lm-sensors

I'm using a fresh install of Ubuntu 16.04 in dualboot with Windows 10 on an Acer VN7-792G

First, it seems that on this laptop the fans would be allowed to go at max to 60% of their max power usage, for the noise I guess. Overheating issues were solved on Windows by tweaking the fans settings to 100% of the use using RWEverything. The fans noise is high but the crashes are gone.

Now on Ubuntu I'm pretty sure the fans aren't spinning at all, which makes the laptop pretty hot, up to 65°c for no reason. I'm just on Firefox.

I installed `lm-sensors` and ran `sensors-detect`, said yes to all. But when I run `sensors` I only get this

```
sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device
temp1:        +58.0°C  (crit = +100.0°C)
temp2:        +45.0°C  (crit = +92.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter
Physical id 0:  +57.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 0:         +51.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 1:         +52.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 2:         +57.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
Core 3:         +52.0°C  (high = +100.0°C, crit = +100.0°C)
```

And of course if I try to use `pwmconfig` it returns `/usr/sbin/pwmconfig: There are no pwm-capable sensor modules installed`

Why are my fans (and others) not detected ?

EDIT : I read online that I might have some missing drivers, and that I should find them, install them and manually add the entry to the etc/modules config file. But I have no idea what driver I'm missing. Here is the result of my `sensors-detect`

http://pastebin.com/5g4ZbxyN

Comment: Possible solution if it has intel fans: [lm-sensors not detecting my fan](http://askubuntu.com/questions/527756/lm-sensors-not-detecting-my-fan)

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't help

Comment: Sorry that I couldn't help.